# Make an imported java class serializable

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In java how do I serialize a class that is not marked Serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114207/in-java-how-do-i-serialize-a-class-that-is-not-marked-serializable)

I am using a custom java class and I am needing to make the class itself serializable since Eclipse is telling me that the class needs this. The problem is however that I do not have the source for this class, only the jar file.

How can I make the object that I am using via importing the jar that contains this object serialiazable, since I do not have the source I cannot simply put in

```
implements Serializable
```

Comment: What exactly is Eclipse telling you? It's not clear why this class really needs to be `Serializable`...

Comment: "I am needing to make the class itself serializable since Eclipse is telling me that the class needs this" - you should make it serializable if you *need to serialize instances*, not just for the sake of it. What are you *really* trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you can create a subclass from this class and implement serializable.

```
 public class MyLocal extends ThirdClass implements Serializable
```

Comment: Yes, assuming it's not a final class, of course!

Comment: was writing exactly the same thing. quick and simple to do ;)

Answer (score 1):

Subclassing (as mentioned) is certainly the most likely to succeed...

Depending on how brave you are (and assuming you are running JDK 6+), you could transform the class on the fly:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/instrumentation/changes6.html

I'm not sure this helps for issues with Eclipse, but could be used to transform a class at runtime.